# nginx fastcgi_cache is only working for 1 website, no other website is getting cached data

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi

I am setting up a new web server and I'm nearly ready to go live but can't iron out 1 last issue - and thats I have multiple WordPress websites setup.

Each WordPress website has its own install and installation directory and a separate database.

I have configured nginx with the `fastcgi_cache` module and it works - but only for the very first website i set up on the server. Every subsequent website gets nothing cached.

Running nginx/php7 on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Here is my `nginx/nginx.conf` file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    add_header rt-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    limit_req_status 403;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    # Log format Settings
    log_format rt_cache '$remote_addr $upstream_response_time $upstream_cache_status [$time_local] ''$http_host "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent ''"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xm image/x-icon text/css text/plain text/x-component text/xml text/javascript;
    # Fastcgi_Cache Additional entries
    add_header Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 444;
    }
}
```

Here is the "cache working" websites config

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/html/1stwebsite.com/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=1stwebsite.com:100m inactive=60m;

server {
    server_name 1stwebsite.com www.1stwebsite.com;
    access_log /var/www/html/1stwebsite.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/1stwebsite.com/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/html/1stwebsite.com/public/;
    index index.php index.html;
    set $skip_cache 0;
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "PHPSESSID"){
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache 1stwebsite.com;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
    }
    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
        fastcgi_cache_purge 1stwebsite.com "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
    }
}
```

Here is 1 of the non working cache websites config (all other non working site configs are the same apart from the website specific info and paths)

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/html/2ndwebiste.co.uk/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=2ndwebiste.co.uk:100m inactive=60m;
server {
    server_name 2ndwebiste.co.uk www.2ndwebiste.co.uk;
    access_log /var/www/html/2ndwebiste.co.uk/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/2ndwebiste.co.uk/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/html/2ndwebiste.co.uk/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $skip_cache 0;
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/phpmyadmin|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "PHPSESSID"){
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/allow_phpmyadmin;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache 2ndwebiste.co.uk;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
    }
    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
        fastcgi_cache_purge 2ndwebiste.co.uk "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
    }
}
```

I think its to do with the very top line of both config files?

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/html/2ndwebiste.co.uk/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=2ndwebiste.co.uk:100m inactive=60m;
```

Does this need to be in the main `nginx.conf` file and not in each individual website config with a single `keys_zone` directive for all websites (ie WORDPRESS)

If so - am i not meant to have a cache folder for each individual website, should there just be 1 central cache folder for all websites?

I thought the `keys_zone` directive needs to be individual for each website, and thus created a seperate cache location for each website hosted.

Thanks to anybody that can walk with me over the finishing line

**UPDATE 17/10/2016**

As requested Tero,

Please see amended configs now:

NGINX.CONF

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    add_header rt-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    limit_req_status 403;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    # Log format Settings
    log_format rt_cache '$remote_addr $upstream_response_time $upstream_cache_status [$time_local] ''$http_host "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent ''"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xm image/x-icon text/css text/plain text/x-component text/xml text/javascript;
    # Fastcgi_Cache Additional entries
    add_header Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/html/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 444;
    }
}
```

WEBSITE1.CONF (That caches ok)

```
server {
    server_name 1stwebsite.com www.1stwebsite.com;
    access_log /var/www/html/1stwebsite.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/1stwebsite.com/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/html/1stwebsite.com/public/;
    index index.php index.html;
    set $skip_cache 0;
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "PHPSESSID"){
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
    }
    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
        fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
    }
}
```

WEBSITE2.COM (that doesnt cache anything)

```
server {
    server_name 2ndwebiste.co.uk www.2ndwebiste.co.uk;
    access_log /var/www/html/2ndwebiste.co.uk/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/2ndwebiste.co.uk/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/html/2ndwebiste.co.uk/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $skip_cache 0;
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/phpmyadmin|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "PHPSESSID"){
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/allow_phpmyadmin;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
    }
    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
        fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `fastcgi_cache_path` three times in the `http` context. Only one of those is used this way.

The correct procedure is to set one cache path for all virtual hosts, and then define `fastcgi_cache_key` inside each `server` block to define unique key for that virtual host's cached files.

For example, you could the following for `1stwebsite.com` server block:

```
fastcgi_cache_key 1stwebsite.com$request_uri;
```

Then, you use same shared memory zone that matches your `fastcgi_cache_path` setting in each of your virtual hosts. For example, if you leave only `fastcgi_cache_path` for your `1stwebsite.com` defined, then your `fastcgi_cache` looks like this everywhere:

```
fastcgi_cache 1stwebsite.com;
```

Comment: Im not quite sure i fully follow your reply...apologies.

Comment: So should it be like this...... take out the fastcgi_cache_path from each of the vhost configs and put a single one into nginx.conf, but instead of calling it per website just call it say "cache" - ie /var/www/html/cache. so directive reads  fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/html/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m;  Then in each vhost config just have fastcgi_cache_key respectivewebsite.com$request_uri; What do i then have as the fastcgi_cache settings in each vhost config if ive set it to WORDPRESS above? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: All other `fastcgi_cache_*` settings are the same inside the virtual host configuration, except for the `fastcgi_cache`, which only refers to the one cache zone defined in `fastcgi_cache_path`.

Comment: Ok so i have changed my configs to this:

Comment: fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/html/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m Inactive=60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

Comment: And made changes to these lines  Removed fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/html/website1.com levels=1:2 keys_zone=website1.com:100m Inactive=60m;  and  fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/html/website2.com levels=1:2 keys_zone=website2.com:100m Inactive=60m;  Changed fastcgi_cache to WORDPRESS  Changed fastcgi_cache_pure to WORDPRESS

Comment: But still website 1 is the only website to populate the cache folder. Website 2 does diddly. What have i missed? Thanks

Comment: Forgot to put - the fastcgi_cache_* changes 3 up from this post are in the nginx.conf file. And the other changes 2 up from this post are in the vhost configs

Comment: Please edit your original question with these configurations so they can be properly formatted.

Comment: Edited as requested Tero. Thankyou